# Does meteor JS supports RTL languages?

Tags: meteor

Does meteor JS supports RTL languages like persian(farsi) or arabic?
When you make web page can you use a right to left language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor is a full-stack framework. On the front-end, it's still HTML/CSS/JS (with a slice of reactive templating on top of it). You can use [i18n packages](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=i18n) to change the user language, or simply hard-code your website in whatever language you want. Right-to-left is managed with CSS, on the front-end.

So yes, Meteor does support right-to-left languages because it's not a front-end framework, but a full-stack one, and you can use any CSS or front-end library with it.

Answer (score 1):

ہاں، یۂ ممكن ہے

Sorry. couldn't resist. Yes, meteor supports unicode languages which include should include all RTL languages supported by unicode.

btw the statement is in urdu and means, yes, it is possible.

Cheers